# Integration of Salesforce SDK with Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipad, salesforce

can any one provide me some useful Information about Integration salesforce SDK with mobile application I am looking to Integrate with iOS7 and android.

Comment: Please check this tutorial for [Android](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Samples/tree/master/Android/tutorials/NativeAndroidTutorial/WarehouseApp/WarehouseApp) **&&** for [iOS](http://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.)

Comment: I hope that, there could be a documentation for it .  **https://raw.github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf**

Comment: but it's for Android is there anything for iOS.

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS

Comment: @spurti check this to get the documents. **https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf?raw=true**

Comment: @guido thanks for suggestion, you can refer the sample @ https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.git
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android.git